# ClickOnce does not copy content files of a .net projet

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, clickonce

I have an issue publishing my .Net application with ClickOnce.
I am trying to publish the application using :

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /m  /target:publish /property:Configuration=Release_REC2

When I am "just" compiling the application everything works fine, but when I attempt to publish it using the above command it omits some dlls in one of the solution's project (ZedModule).

Here is the ZedModule.csproj file :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{5B091DB7-41A2-496B-8001-69DEA7297100}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Contacts14.ZedModule</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Contacts14.ZedModule</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Geckofx-Core, Version=45.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3209ac31600d1857, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\GeckoFx\Geckofx-Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Geckofx-Winforms, Version=45.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3209ac31600d1857, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\GeckoFx\Geckofx-Winforms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Desktop.Infrastructure">
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Desktop.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Core, Version=8.5.135.5, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Voice, Version=8.5.135.5, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Voice.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Windows, Version=8.5.135.5, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Desktop.Modules.Windows.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Desktop.WPFCommon, Version=8.5.135.5, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Desktop.WPFCommon.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Enterprise.Model, Version=8.5.135.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95e512acdb150ec7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Enterprise.Model.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Platform.Commons.Collections, Version=9.0.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2248646200015f60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Platform.Commons.Collections.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Platform.Commons.Protocols, Version=9.0.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2248646200015f60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Platform.Commons.Protocols.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Genesyslab.Platform.Voice.Protocols, Version=9.0.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2248646200015f60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Genesyslab.Platform.Voice.Protocols.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\References\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IZedButtonView.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IZedView.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\IZedService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\ZedRequest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\ZedResponse.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Services\ZedService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Views\ZedButtonView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ZedButtonView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\ZedMessageBox.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ZedMessageBox.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Views\ZedView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ZedView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ZedCreationButton.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ZedCreationButton.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ZedModule.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="omni.ja">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="Views\ZedButtonView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\ZedMessageBox.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Views\ZedView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="ZedCreationButton.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Images\ZedWhite.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contacts14.Core\Contacts14.Core.csproj">
      <Project>{AC8E6258-6988-40CF-9854-F6A9A3455F35}</Project>
      <Name>Contacts14.Core</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contacts14.GEDModule\Contacts14.GEDModule.csproj">
      <Project>{28402E94-9B02-41A6-B442-6D73838D6584}</Project>
      <Name>Contacts14.GEDModule</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contacts14.Models\Contacts14.Models.csproj">
      <Project>{8316D803-569E-4E07-B1E0-5B20860EAA45}</Project>
      <Name>Contacts14.Models</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contacts14.Services\Contacts14.Services.csproj">
      <Project>{72C75C60-FFDD-4505-8F18-CF02608568A0}</Project>
      <Name>Contacts14.Services</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AccessibleMarshal.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="breakpadinjector.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Contacts14.ZedModule.module-config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="D3DCompiler_43.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="d3dcompiler_47.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="freebl3.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="icudt56.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="icuin56.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="icuuc56.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="lgpllibs.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="libEGL.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="libGLESv2.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="mozglue.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="msvcp120.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="msvcr120.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="nss3.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="nssckbi.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="nssdbm3.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="plugin-container.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="plugin-hang-ui.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="sandboxbroker.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="softokn3.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="xul.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

The problem is that the ZedModule.dll.deploy is correctly copied in the published folder. But all of the content dlls : xul.dll, softokn3.dll, etc... are not

Any idea what I am missing here ?

I have been using this command forever and I am having this problem only since I created this new ZedModule project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Copy Always" instead of "Copy if newer"? To do so just change

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

to

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

for each class.

Comment: Hi yes I did try that. But that did not change anything. Plus the "regular" comilation works fine. It is juste the /target:publish that ignores the dlls. Oddly enough the project itself build and is copied fine.